# Setting initial selection value along with observer method

Tags: ember.js

I have a select box where I am firing a method on change and I also need to set the initial selected value. The firing method works great but I can't seem to get the default option working along with it.

Controller:

```
TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  users: Em.computed -> @store.findAll 'user'

  selectedUserDidChange: Em.observer 'selectedUser', ->
    if @get 'selectedUser' then @assignUser()

  assignee: Em.computed 'model', -> 4 # Just as a test

  assignUser: ->
    model = @get 'model'
    model.set 'assigneeId', @get('selectedUser').get('id')
    unless model.save()
      console.log 'Error: TodoModuleController.assignUser'
```

Template:

```
  <p>Assign-to:</p>
  {{view Em.Select content=users value=assignee selection=selectedUser optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.firstName'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `selectedUser` to a one-time computed property that you then override via the selection binding. For example:

```
selectedUser: Em.computed -> @get('users').objectAt 0
```

The idea is to pass a model that the select can match against. This should also be ignored by the observer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well that looks fantastic but I can't get it to work and I'm not sure why. I did the following: selectedUser: Em.computed -> @get('users').objectAt(3) and switched out 3 with other numbers but none of them work.

Comment: Actually looking at it I think it's something to do with users not being resolved at that point. Thanks again for the help Matthew!